# Working with NSTableView in Swift

Tags: swift, nstableview

I'm a newcomer to xcode and Swift and I was wondering if there was any simple way to add cells to a Table View similar to the method of adding selections to a Combo Box. Here's my code so far.

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelout: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var partitionbox: NSComboBox!
@IBOutlet weak var comboboxtext: NSComboBoxCell!
@IBOutlet weak var launchtable: NSTableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tabletext: NSTextFieldCell!
@IBOutlet weak var pathlist: NSCell!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    partitionbox.removeAllItems()
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var error: NSError? = nil
    let contents = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/Volumes", error: &error)
        partitionbox.addItemsWithObjectValues(contents!)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the
}

@IBAction func refreshbuttonpress(sender: AnyObject) {
    partitionbox.removeAllItems()
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let contents = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/Volumes", error: &error)
    partitionbox.addItemsWithObjectValues(contents!)
}

@IBAction func inspectbuttonpress(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let part = comboboxtext.stringValue
    let directory = part + "/Library/LaunchAgents"
    let cellcontent = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/Library/LaunchAgents", error: &error)

    //  Anything similar to addItemsWithObjectValues for TableView?

        }
override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

My application aim is to have a list of all LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons and Frameworks installed to an OS.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nstableview-sample-code/

Comment: Thank you. Not enough swift and Xcode 6 documentation out there.

Comment: You should add NSTableView Delegate and Datasource methods. I recommend downloading any sample from the developer website, NSTableView or OutlineView. Or even the link above.